# Solve $\cos(x) = \cos(x+a)$, if $\cos(x)\ge0$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $\cos(x) = \cos(x+a)$, if $\cos(x)\ge0$

This is how I did it:

For $\cos(x)\ge0, x\in[(4n-1)\frac\pi2,(4n+1)\frac\pi2]$

Also, $\cos(x+a)\ge0\implies x+a\in[(4m-1)\frac\pi2,(4m+1)\frac\pi2]$

$$\cos(x+a)=\cos(x)\\x+a=2n\pi\pm x$$
**Case I**: Taking the $+$ sign,
$a=2n\pi$
For these values of $a$, $x\in[(4n-1)\frac\pi2,(4n+1)\frac\pi2]$. This also satisfies the condition that $\cos(x+a)\ge0$
**Case II** Taking the $-$ sign,
$x=\frac{2n\pi+a}{2}$
How do I solve the rest of it, satisfying the conditions on $x$ and $a$ simultaneously? Should I replace $x$ with $\frac{2n\pi+a}{2}$ in the first two conditions or do something else?

Comment: Rather than considering where $\cos(x)\ge 0$, try solving the two equations $±\cos(x) = \cos(x+a)$

Comment: @Mathmo123 Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mathmo says, solve the resulting equation after expanding using the identity for cosine of the sum:

$$\cos(x)=\cos(x+a)\Rightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)=\cos(x)\cos(a)-\sin(x)\sin(a)\Rightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)\cdot(\cos(a)-1)=\sin(x)\sin(a)\Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{-1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\Rightarrow$$
$$\tan(x)=\frac{-1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\Rightarrow$$
$$x=\arctan\left(\frac{-1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\right )$$

Comment: The interesting part is that you obtain $x=a$ within the domain $a \in [-\pi,+\pi]$ and $x=0$ for $a=0$, but $a=0$ has many solutions as $\cos(x) = \cos(x)$...

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28+%281-cos%28a%29%29%2Fsin%28a%29+%29

Comment: You must exclude $a=0$ when you divide by $\sin(a)$...

Comment: @johannessvalks: Agreed on both counts, of course. It was just the mechanics modulo (the) minor details.

Comment: But what about satisfying the conditions that $\cos(x), \cos(x+a)\ge0$. The answer in my book considers various possible values of $a$ and gives corresponding values of $x$ for them.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
\cos(x+a) = \cos(x).
$$

---

Write this as

$$
\cos(x+a) - \cos(x) = 0,
$$

thus

$$
\cos\Big( (x+a/2) + a/2 \Big) - \cos\Big( (x+a/2) - a/2 \Big) = 0,
$$

which can be written as

$$
2 \sin\Big( x+a/2 \Big) \sin\Big( a/2 \Big) = 0,
$$

therefore

$$
a = 2 k \pi \vee a = 2k\pi - 2x.
$$

---

As

$$
\cos(x) \ge 0,
$$

we have

$$
x \in \Big[2\ell\pi - \tfrac{1}{2}\pi,2\ell\pi + \tfrac{1}{2}\pi\Big],
$$.

so

$$
2x \in \Big[4\ell\pi - \pi,4\ell\pi + \pi\Big]
$$

and

$$
2x - 2k\pi \in \Big[2 (2\ell - k) \pi - \pi,2(2\ell-k)\pi + \pi\Big],
$$

but

$$
\Big[2 (2\ell - k) \pi - \pi,2(2\ell-k)\pi + \pi\Big] =
\Big[2 m - \pi, 2 m + \pi \Big] = \mathbb{R},
$$

so

$$
a \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

---

For a given $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$
a - 2\pi \Big\lfloor \frac{a+\pi}{2\pi} \Big\rfloor
\in \Big[-\pi,+\pi\Big],
$$

so

$$
- \tfrac{1}{2} a + \pi \Big\lfloor \frac{a+\pi}{2\pi} \Big\rfloor
\in \Big[-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi,\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\Big],
$$

whence

$$
2\ell\pi - \tfrac{1}{2} a + \pi \Big\lfloor \frac{a+\pi}{2\pi} \Big\rfloor
\in \Big[2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi,2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\Big].
$$

We also have

$$
x = k\pi - \tfrac{1}{2} a
\in \Big[2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi,2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\Big],
$$

therefore

$$
x = 2\ell\pi - \tfrac{1}{2} a + \pi \Big\lfloor \frac{a+\pi}{2\pi} \Big\rfloor
\in \Big[2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi,2\ell\pi-\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\Big],
$$

and the solution for $x$.

Comment: That's what I did...The answer in my book considers various possible values of $a$ and gives corresponding values of $x$ for them. The '$a=2k\pi$' is easy but what about the $a=2k\pi-2x$, since we have the condition that $/cos(x), /cos(x+a) \ge 0$.

Comment: I have added that condition in detail...

Comment: Is it $[(2m-1)\pi, (2m+1)\pi]$?

Comment: No it is $[(2m-\tfrac{1}{2})\pi,(2m+\tfrac{1}{2})\pi]$. Note that $[(2m-1)\pi,(2m+1)\pi] = \mathbb{R}$, as $2(m+1)-1 = 2m+1$...